# How to customize BooleanInput to add or remove items from a list?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

I am using the awesome react-admin library and looking for a way to customize BooleanInput field.

The following use case: I have an array of rights given to a user. E.g.

```
user: {
  rights: ["REGULAR", "VIP", "ADMIN"],
  otherFields...
}
```

and the UX requirement is to have an booleanInput to indicate if a user has a certain right. E.g. if the `rights` array contains `VIP`, then the BooleanInput should be set to true. If a user set it to false, `VIP` should be removed from the array and vice versa.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is transforming input to suite your needs
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record

```
<BooleanInput source="rights" format={v => v.includes("VIP")} parse={v => {if(v){ //return array including vip} else {// return array excluding vip}}} label="Admin" />
```

Comment: Hi Prakash,
thank you! That is the right direction. I am still struggling with two errors:
1) When a load the page for the first time, `v` is undefined, so it crashed
2) After reloading  the page (the record is not retrieved from the API I get `Error: Cannot set a numeric property on an object`

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @Hola what is the response from API looks like

Comment: its an array of strings with dynamic number of items. E.g.

"rights": [
    "REGULAR",
    "VIP",
   "OTHER_VALUES"
  ]

Comment: @Hola I meant whole api response

Comment: Made a mistake in the comment above. Here is the object

`{
  "id" : "152",
  "image" : "https:/cdn.image-server.com/defaultProfilePic.jpg",
  "username" : "somemeamail@someemail.com",
  "firstName" : "FirstName",
  "lastName" : "LastName",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2019-07-10T17:32:23.110Z",
  "isVerified" : true, 
  "rights" : [ "VIP", "USER" ]
}`